# C++ knapsack implementation

Tags: c++, knapsack-problem

I have a problem with my knapsack algorithm. To be honest I dont have idea what is wrong. When I use program once, all works wrong, but when I gonna use my program in loop (for test) I have a lot problem.

For example:
Weight/Val in file : 100
max knapsack capacity: 1000
**First iteration:**
Max profit: 2597
The resulting weight: 994/1000
And its fine, but now another iteration.
**Second iteration:**
Max profit: 2538
**The resulting weight: 1004/1000** <- and there is my problem, its over my max cap.
3rd,4th were okey, then 5th was wrong (1355/1000), and so on.

My function where is possible problem:

```
    void intoKnapsack(int k, float actual_profit, float actual_weight)
{
    if (actual_weight + weight[k] <= cap)
    {
        tmp[k] = 1;
        if (k <= number_items)
            intoKnapsack(k + 1, actual_profit + value[k], actual_weight + weight[k]);
        if (((actual_profit + value[k]) > final_profit) && (k == number_items))
        {
            final_profit = actual_profit + value[k];
            final_weight = actual_weight + weight[k];
            for (j = 0; j <= k; j++)
                knap[j] = tmp[j];
        }
    }
    else if ((bound(actual_profit, actual_weight, k) >= final_profit))
    {
        tmp[k] = 0;
        if (k <= number_items)
            intoKnapsack(k + 1, actual_profit, actual_weight);
        if ((actual_profit > final_profit) && (k == number_items))
        {
            final_profit = actual_profit;
            final_weight = actual_weight;
            for (j = 0; j <= k; j++)
                knap[j] = tmp[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help with my problem?

Comment: Any chance you could translate the polish code? Otherwise we can't read it.

Comment: Done :D Now should be easier

Comment: Rough translation: http://pastebin.com/xVZXFDp4 (Thanks, google translate lol). **Edit**: Ah, he translated it himself about 30 seconds before I finished translating via Google Translate xD

Comment: So we have 2 translates :P
Anyway, still dont have idea what did wrong, tried to change few things, but without succ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so when I ready only once the same N (like 100 in example above) then it works fine, but when I do it in loop:

```
                srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
                algorytm a;
                fstream wynik;
                wynik.open("result.txt",ios::out | ios::app);
                for(int i=0; i<how_test; i++){ //how many tests
                    write(how_n); //how many n in my file, and create file
                    a.read()      //read from file (n, and weight / val)
                    time_start(); 
                    a.sort();     //I sort it
                    a.intoKnapsack(0, 0.0, 0.0); //my function above, so I give here a 3x to do it properly over and over in loop
                    get_time();  //stop time
                    measurement+=get_time(); 
                    result<<get_time()<<" s."<<endl; //just for 
                }
```

so when I do by myself for example write(50), then in same program write(51) and so on it works good, but when I do write(50), then another write(50), then I have wrong algorithm.
Maybe when I do sort, before clear Knapsack it in another loop doesnt work, but in other hand I first need to do sort.
There is my sort function

```
void algorytm::sort() {

    int a;
    int b;
    float c;
    for (i = 0; i < number_items; i++)
        factor[i] = (float) val[i] / (float) weight[i]; //to sort from best to worst
    for (i = 0; i < number_items - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < number_items; j++) {
            if (factor[i] < factor[j]) {
                c = factor[i];                            //
                factor[i] = factor[j];
                factor[j] = c;
                a = val[i];                                 //
                val[i] = val[j];
                val[j] = a;
                b = weight[i];                                    //
                weight[i] = weight[j];
                weight[j] = b;
            }
        }
    }
}
```